# Ubuntu с урезанным ядром

Tags: linux, ubuntu, install

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, есть мини ПК на него необходимо поставить образ очень сильно урезанной Ubuntu. Есть установочный диск, при начале установки через 10-15 секунд вываливается ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как в мини ПК нет дисковода был взят внешний по USB. Пробовал записать образ на флешку там даже не начинается установка , сразу падает в ошибку. Может кто нибудь подскажет что нибудь.

Comment: Так повыкидывпйте службы ненужные из загрузки, для этого загрузитесь в `single` режиме.

Comment: @NewView не помогло) Может еще накинешь мыслей а то я уже не могу.

Comment: Может быть это стоит упомянуть что стоит ссд м2 которая вроде как определяется через sata и я где то читал что в этом может быть проблемма

Comment: На мой взгляд проблема в том что оно виснет на процессе загрузки чего то там.. надо смотреть логи, и все же грузиться в сингл режиме. Это при старте через lilo/grub надо указать параметр в списке строки определения кернеля - single.

Comment: @NewView так я так и сделал, объясните по поводу логов,  при вылете ошибки перестает отвечать клавиатура и мышка и я не могу ничего сделать кроме как ребута

Comment: А чё не `Alpine`?

Comment: @donRumata там готовое решение под систему управления. Я бы рад туда что угодно сделать но это готовый дистрибутив который общается с устройством

Comment: А выложить этот iso в открытый доступ - сильно нельзя?

Comment: А что, из приведенного вами скрина, вы считаете ошибкой? Система загрузилась, оболочка BusyBox готова к работе. Если что то было до, то на скрине этого не видно. У вас даже некоторые сервисы (sshd, vsdftpd, telnet) стартовали.